# Tips/Tools for working with SQLite in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, rdbms

I'm a .NET developer starting to dig into an android application. One thing that seems a little abstract is working with SqlLite. In a .NET application, I can do my Database setup, query testing and profiling, and enter in some test records through Management Studio for MSSQL. In fact, I'm constantly in Management Studio checking something - so I'm finding it difficult to work without a similar tool.

What are some good tools/tricks to use when developing SQLLite on Android? The tool doesn't have to have a GUI, but would be nice if I could run it as a desktop app and have it look at the same DB as my emulator.

For instance, something that will allow me to run a simple SELECT statement against a table to view records without having to do it through android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some tools:

```
http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/
http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/
http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools
```

So, for instance install sqlite manager for firefox, run your app in an eclipse emulator, copy the db file to firefox, and now you can view your db and run queries.

Comment: +1 just tried sqlliteadmin, great advice, works like a charm. thx!

Answer (score 1):

Give [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) a try. I use it with the db files I grab from the device.

Comment: you can connect to the database on the emulator or on a physical device?

Comment: No, I usually download the sqlite file from my dev device using "adb pull" then I open the file with the app I mentioned.